# R: What are dates in a dates vector: dates or numeric values? (difference between x[i] and i)

Tags: r, date

Could anyone explain please why in the first loop each element of my dates vector is a date while in the second each element of my dates vector is numeric?
Thank you!

```
x <- as.Date(c("2018-01-01", "2018-01-02", "2018-01-02", "2018-05-06"))
class(x)
# Loop 1 - each element is a Date:
for (i in seq_along(x)) print(class(x[i]))
# Loop 2 - each element is numeric:
for (i in x) print(class(i))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run:

```
for (i in seq_along(x)) print(class(x[i]))
```

You're using an iterator `i` over each element of `x`. Which means that each time you get the class of each iterated member of `x`.

However, when you run:

```
for (i in x) print(class(i))
```

You're looking for the class of each member. Using the `?Date`:

> Dates are represented as the number of days since 1970-01-01

Which is the reason why you get numeric as your class.

Moreover, if you'll use `print()` for each loop you'll get dates and numbers:

```
for (i in seq_along(x)) print(x[i])

[1] "2018-01-01"
[1] "2018-01-02"
[1] "2018-01-02"
[1] "2018-05-06"
```

and

```
for (i in x) print(i)

[1] 17532
[1] 17533
[1] 17533
[1] 17657
```

Lastly, if you want to test R's logic we can do something like that:

```
x[1] - as.Date("1970-01-01")
```

Taking the first element of x ("2018-01-01") and subtract "1970-01-01", which is the first date. Our output will be:

```
Time difference of 17532 days
```

Answer (score 8):

The elements are `Date`, the first loop is correct.

Unfortunately R does not consistently have the style of the second loop. I believe that the issue is that the `for (i in x)` syntax bypasses the `Date` methods for accessors like `[`, which it can do because S3 classes in R are very thin and don't prevent you from not using their intended interfaces. This can be confusing because something like `for (i in 1:4) print(i)` works directly, since numeric is a base vector type. `Date` is S3, so it is coerced to numeric. To see the numeric objects that are printing in the second loop, you can run this:

```r
x <- as.Date(c("2018-01-01", "2018-01-02", "2018-01-02", "2018-05-06"))
for (i in x) print(i)
#> [1] 17532
#> [1] 17533
#> [1] 17533
#> [1] 17657
```

which is giving you the same thing as the unclassed version of the `Date` vector. These numbers are the days since the beginning of Unix time, which you can also see below if you convert them back to `Date` with that `origin`.

```r
unclass(x)
#> [1] 17532 17533 17533 17657
as.Date(unclass(x), "1970-01-01")
#> [1] "2018-01-01" "2018-01-02" "2018-01-02" "2018-05-06"
```

So I would stick to using the proper accessors for any S3 vector types as you do in the first loop.

Comment: @IceCreamToucan Even more directly, `as.vector(x)` yields the underlying integers. The documentation is excessively cryptic about this issue, though, imho.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at `?'for'`, you'll see that `for(var in seq)` is only defined when `seq` is "An expression evaluating to a vector", and `is.vector(x)` is `FALSE`. So the documentation says (maybe not so clearly) that the behavior here is undefined, which is why the behavior is unexpected.

As joran mentions, `as.vector(x)` returns a numeric vector, same as `unclass(x)` mentioned by Calum You.